# Python fdpexpect with multiple expects

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect

Testing the simple example that should execute the external application and catch both inputs there.

```
# external_application.py
print('First_line:')
x = input()

print('Second_line:')
y = input()

print(f'Done: {x} and {y}')
```

And the runner:

```
# runner.py
import subprocess
import pexpect.fdpexpect

p = subprocess.Popen(("python", "external_application.py"), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

session = pexpect.fdpexpect.fdspawn(p.stdout.fileno())

session.expect("First_line:")
p.stdin.write(b'1')
print('first_done')

session.expect("Second_line:")
p.stdin.write(b'2')
print('second_done')

p.stdin.close()
print(f'Result: {p.stdout.read()}')
```

I can see that output of the `print('first_done')` and then it locks on the second `expect`. If we remove the second `input` and a second `expect` then everything works correctly till the end.
Running on the windows, python 3.7.9, pexpect 4.8.0
Am I missing some timeout or a flush?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I check the dump, `session` matches `b'First_line:\r\n'`, but `p.stdin.write` doesn't move the pexpect cursor forward to look for `"Second_line:"`, as what happens with `send()` or `sendline()`.

May I suggest a simpler way, using [PopenSpawn](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/popen_spawn.html)? The docs state that it "*provides an interface like pexpect.spawn interface (sic) using subprocess.Popen*":

**NOTE** - Tested in Windows 11, using Python 3.9.

```
import pexpect
from pexpect import popen_spawn

session = pexpect.popen_spawn.PopenSpawn("python external_application.py")
session.expect("First_line:")
session.sendline("1")
print("first_done")

session.expect("Second_line:")
session.sendline("2")
print("second_done")

print(session.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

**Output:**

```
first_done
second_done

Done: 1 and 2
```

Comment: I've also during the tests noticed the same thing about the incorrect parsing after you do `stdin.write`.